# Split data (dynamic result) in to 3 columns - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, split, html-table, multiple-columns

Need to split result ( dynamic - mysql ) into columns ( as per define below $cols )

*Note: if anyone have solution in any other format please let me know ...*

```
$cols=3; // note i can change this to 4,5 ..2 etc..

echo "<table border='0'  align='center' valign='top' >";
do{
        echo "<tr>";
                    for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){    
            $rowsA=data_fetch($sqlquery);
                        if($rowsA){
        echo'<td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table  border="1px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                        <tr align="center" valign="top">';
                                echo '<td class="dateis" align="center" valign="top" width="35px"> <strong>'.$srno.'</strong> </td>';
                                echo '<td class="dateis" align="center" valign="top" width="100px">'.$rowsA['prdname'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td class="dateis" align="center" valign="top" width="50px">'.number_format($rowsA['prdwgh'],3,'.','').'</td> 
                                    </tr>';
                                   $srno++;
                       echo'</tr>
                    </table>
        </td>';
    } else{
          }
      }
    } while($rowsA);
    echo "</table>";
```

**Hence from above i get below display :**

```
1 Prda 1.4  |  2 prdan  2.3  |  3  prdbc  3.1
4 prdf 0.02 |  5 prdcv  1.0  |  6  prdd   0.9
7 prdc 0.3  |  8 prdbn  2.8  |  9  prdf   0.5
```

***but i need as below :***

```
1 Prda 1.4     |  4 prdf   0.02    |  7  prdc   0.3 
2 prdan  2.3   |  5 prdcv  1.0     |  8  prdbn  2.8
3 prdbc  3.1   |  6 prdd   0.9     |  9  prdf   0.5
```

Update :

***if there is 10 records :***

```
1 Prda 1.4     |  5 prdcv  1.0    |  9  prdf   0.5
2 prdan  2.3   |  6 prdd   0.9    |  10 prdf   2.5
3 prdbc  3.1   |  7 prdc   0.3    |  
4 prdf   0.02  |  8 prdbn  2.8    |
```

***if there is 11 records :***

```
1 Prda 1.4     |  5 prdcv  1.0    |  9  prdf   0.5
2 prdan  2.3   |  6 prdd   0.9    |  10 prdf   2.5
3 prdbc  3.1   |  7 prdc   0.3    |  11 prdfd  2.1
4 prdf   0.02  |  8 prdbn  2.8    |
```

Thanks

Comment: if anyone have solution in any different way ..will do that to... thanks

Comment: any one please help me....

Comment: Suppose $cols=4, then upto where it will display?

Comment: then there will be fourth column... at last

Comment: @santhy , can u please tell me solution with $cols=3 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample for cols = 3. Please tweak with your db name and its column. hope this results as you expected.

```
$NoOfColumns = 3;
$dataArr = $matrixArr = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM testDb ORDER BY prdname";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("error getting data");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($dataArr, $row);
}
$totalCnt = count($dataArr);
$NoOfRows = floor($totalCnt / $NoOfColumns);
if ($havRem = $totalCnt % $NoOfColumns) {
    $NoOfRows++;
}
$matrixArr = array_chunk($dataArr , $NoOfRows);

//echo "<pre>";print_r($dataArr);echo "</pre>";
//echo "<pre>";print_r($matrixArr);echo "</pre>";

echo "<table border=1>";
for ($row = 0; $row < $NoOfRows; $row++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $srno = $row+1;
    for ($col = 0; $col < $NoOfColumns; $col++) {        
    echo'<td align="center" valign="top">';
            if ($srno<=$totalCnt) {
             echo   '<table  border="1px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr align="center" valign="top">';
                            echo '<td class="dateis" align="center" valign="top" width="35px"> <strong>'.$srno.'</strong> </td>';
                            echo '<td class="dateis" align="center" valign="top" width="100px">'.$matrixArr[$col][$row]['prdname'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td class="dateis" align="center" valign="top" width="50px">'.$matrixArr[$col][$row]['prdwgh'].'</td> 
                                </tr>';

                   echo'</tr>
                </table>';
            }
    echo '</td>';
    $srno = $srno+$NoOfRows;
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: thanks its working but as you know my data are dynamic hence if i have 10 records ...then as per u r above structure its showing only 9 records ...the 10 records is hide ... also i tested with $NoOfColumns = 4; its working but same ..10 records is not show ...

Comment: oh you mean according to the data count the num of colums will increase. say 9 then 3, 10 to 12 then 4 colm, 13 to 15 then 5 etc...?

Comment: no numberofcol will be set as per its variable ..but row need to be updated ..please se my update question